# What is the difference between width percentage% and pixels in css

Tags: html, css, width, division

I have created a header and I've given it 100% width size.

Now I am trying to put the text centered in this width by using `padding-right` and `left` and how many pixels from left to right or right to left will make it center,

Again my question is how many px is equal to percentage?

If I have given it 100% width then it is equal to how many px?

I am also putting my code below so you can better understand my question

**html section:**

```html
<header>
    <nav id="logo-menu">
    <nav id="logo">Logo</nav>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**css:**

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header{
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

#logo-menu{
    height: 80px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: bisque;
}

#logo{
    height: 80px;
    width: 50%;
    color: black;
    border: 0.1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}

#menu{
    height: 80px;
    width: 49%;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

So basically I am trying to put `li` items in the middle.

I am a new HTML/CSS learner and need your help guys.

Comment: do you want to align the li items vertical?

Answer (score 2):

### About the questions

Pixels (an absolute value) and percentage (a relative value) cannot be derived each other.
Let me explain.
If you use a fixed value like `width:250px` you will have 250 pixels.
If you use a relative value it will change depending from other values.
*width* percentage returns a value related to the container.
If your container is 1000px large and you use `width: 20%`, it results to be 200 pixels.
If the container size depends from something else (depending from the screen resolution for example) you will not know how many pixels will be the defined percentage.

To center a child element in a container use: `margin: auto`
You can specify margin-top/margin-bottom after that if you want to change the vertical position.

See the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width

> #### length
>
> Defines the width as an absolute value.
>
> #### percentage
>
> Defines the width as a percentage of the containing
>   block's content width. If the width of the containing block depends on
>   the width of the element, the resulting layout is undefined.

---

### About the specific problem

If I understood correctly and you want the "li" elements centered in the (already centered) "ul", this is how I did it:

```css
#menu ul {
    text-align: center;
}
```

I used a more specific selector (*#menu ul* means the UL element child of the element with id="menu") because I don't want this behavior for all the UL eelments in the page.

Comment: Hi, Alex thanks a lot for your answer, now I got it, thanks a lot.